# Having error while executing postgresqlquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I am facing error in my query while deleting row from two table which have same primary and foreign key :
Query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.id=TABLE2.id) WHERE TABLE1.id='21306';
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"

Using rdbms POSTGRESQL

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 and 9.5 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Just as expected. Do WHERE EXISTS instead.

Comment: That syntax simply isn't correct. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a join in the from clause of a `delete` in Postgresql (although this is supported in SQL Server). Any additional table that you want to participate in the delete must be added to the `using` clause. Try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
 USING TABLE2 
 WHERE (TABLE1.id=TABLE2.id) AND TABLE1.id='21306';
```

Comment: I want to delete record from both the tables

Comment: You can only delete from one table using one delete statement. You can delete from multiple tables in a single SQL statement using a `WITH` statement

Comment: @Dungeonwolf: then you need to run two DELETE statements.

Comment: is it possible to delete record  from both table using a single query?

Comment: can i get a query using with statement?

Comment: You could try this: `WITH d as (delete from table1 using table2 
where (table1.id=table2.id) and table1.id='21306') delete from table2 using table1 
where (table1.id=table2.id) and table1.id='21306'`

Comment: Error executing sql statement: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 221 now facing this

Comment: It looks like your id column is a number. Don't put the 21306 in quotes.

Comment: removed quotes still facing this

Comment: @Dungeonwolf: I can't think of anything else. Check the types of the `id` column of both table1 and table2. They should be the same, otherwise cast one to the other. Make sure you removed all quotes around the numbers as such: `WITH d as (delete from table1 using table2  where (table1.id=table2.id) and table1.id=21306) delete from table2 using table1  where (table1.id=table2.id) and table1.id=21306`